# put ALSA as module ERROR

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, alsa

I've got a problem. I have to enable on my kernel ALSA from built-in to Module because I need to install Realtek linux driver for ALC260. If I change it in my kernel configuration and I run make command I get these errors:

```
drivers/built-in.o: In function `mxc_hdmi_register_audio':
clkdev.c:(.text+0x6cc44): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_link_rwlock'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `mxc_hdmi_abort_stream':
clkdev.c:(.text+0x6ccfc): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_link_rwlock'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `asrc_init':
clkdev.c:(.init.text+0x7b34): undefined reference to `asrc_p2p_hook'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `asrc_exit':
clkdev.c:(.exit.text+0xe74): undefined reference to `asrc_p2p_hook'
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Errore 1
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Why do you think you need to install a Realtek driver?

Answer (score 0):

First run `make distclean`. Then enter `make menuconfig` and make changes. Then enter `make`. It will compile without error.